# Adding a simple shrink animation to my current js/css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Morning

I have added some js/css to make a logo in a navbar resize on scroll, I was wondering if I could add in something to make it animated so rather than just being the new size it shrinks down and then grows back up.

When the logo currently does resize it loads quite badly (almost pixelated) for the first second or so and then smooths itself out, could someone explain what might be causing that and if it is avoidable?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).on("scroll",function(){
    if(jQuery(document).scrollTop()>100){
        console.log('scrolled')
        jQuery(".responsive-logo").removeClass("largelogo").addClass("smalllogo");
        jQuery("#main-nav").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        jQuery("#menu-menu-1").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
        jQuery(".menu-item").removeClass("large").addClass("small");
    } else{
        console.log('notscrolled')
        jQuery(".responsive-logo").removeClass("smalllogo").addClass("largelogo");
        jQuery("#main-nav").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
        jQuery("#menu-menu-1").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
        jQuery(".menu-item").removeClass("small").addClass("large");
    }
});
```

```
    .smalllogo{
            width: 40px;
            height: auto;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
        }

.largelogo{
            display:block;
        }

.small{
            padding-top: 0px !important;
            min-height: 0px !important;
            margin-top: 0px !important;
            max-height: 60px !important;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Jquery Animate()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp)

It will help you animate stuff easily

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation on the browser pixel rendering and what happens when it's trying to deal with arbitrary values. It might be enough to specify `-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;` and see if that makes it less obvious? It sounds like `ease` (default) might be causing an issue for you.